# What is the relationship between functions and expected values?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

Imagine a random variable $X$ and a function $f(x)$.

What properties must $f(x)$ have for $f(E[X]) = E[f(X)]$.

Example: Do we know the average kinetic energy of a set of particles, if we know the average speed?

Here, $f(v) = \dfrac12 m v^2$

Comment: Generally this will only be true if $f$ is linear.

Comment: Yeah, variable x, not function. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ should be an affine function, i.e. $f(x)=ax+b$ for some $a, b$. This follows from linearity of integration.

In general, otherwise, the equality does not hold.

Comment: +1 Correct. Without additional info we can not claim anything and the equality does not usually hold.